# Exclude external uri for css and js version

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style

I use the following code to add version `?ver=xxx` based on file last modified date to css and js. It works fine, but when I use external assets, it runs into errors, as `get_theme_file_uri()`, and `get_theme_file_path()` won't work anymore.

```
//fonts.googleapis.com/...
//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/...
```

Is it possible to fix that? Perhaps not to have the `?ver` or use the WP default versioning system `ver=4.8` ... for remote assets instead.

Other than that, can the code below be simplified slightly if possible?

```
function _enqueue_scripts() {

    function style($handle, $file, $deps=array(), $media='all') {
        $src = get_theme_file_uri($file);
        $ver = md5(filemtime(get_theme_file_path($file)));
        wp_enqueue_style($handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $media);
    }

    function script($handle, $file, $deps=array(), $in_footer='true') {
        $src = get_theme_file_uri($file);
        $ver = md5(filemtime(get_theme_file_path($file)));
        wp_enqueue_script($handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $in_footer);
    }

    style('_normalize', '/assets/css/normalize.css');
    style('_base', '/assets/css/base.css');
    style('_fonts', '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600');

    script('_lightbox2', '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightbox2/2.9.0/js/lightbox.min.js', array('jquery'));
    script('_base', '/assets/js/base.js', array('jquery'));

    if (is_singular() && comments_open() && get_option('thread_comments')) {
        wp_enqueue_script('comment-reply');
    }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', '_enqueue_scripts');
```

Comment: you could use an additional parameter to indicate it is remote, and not use get_theme_file_path in that case. You also don't need to declare the functions inside _enqueue_scripts.

Comment: other options are just directly using wp_enqueue_script/style when using remote files with standard version numbers or saving local copies of the script

Comment: @inarilo Would you like to post it to an answer and why moving the functions out is better please?

Comment: Why not just directly use `wp_enqueue_script` for external URLs?

Comment: @JackJohansson You're right, but just to see if there are better options.

Comment: The provided answer shows research and is valuable. But honestly, how do you think writing custom functions is better than just using the native wp functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declaring functions inside functions can lead to problems as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1631579/1228379

To solve the issue of remote files, you can use an additional parameter to indicate it is remote (or local) and call get_theme_file_uri/path accordingly. Alternatively, you can just call wp_enqueue_script/style directly and use standard version numbers, or simply save the files locally.

In addition, if you find it simpler, you can also combine the two functions as one and pass some of the parameters as an associative array ($args need only contain the values you want to change):

```
function myenqueuer($handle, $src, $args) {
    $defaults = array('type'      => 'script',
                      'local'     => true,
                      'deps'      => array(),
                      'media'     => 'all',
                      'in_footer' => true,
                      'ver'       => false);
    $args = wp_parse_args($args, $defaults);
    if($args['local']) {
        $args['ver'] = md5(filemtime(get_theme_file_path($src)));
        $src = get_theme_file_uri($src);
    }
    if($args['type'] == 'style') {
        wp_enqueue_style($handle, $src, $args['deps'], $args['ver'], $args['media']);
    } else if($args['type'] == 'script') {
        wp_enqueue_script($handle, $src, $args['deps'], $args['ver'], $args['in_footer']);
    }
}
```

You would call it like this:

```
myenqueuer('_normalize', '/assets/css/normalize.css', array('type'=>'style'));
myenqueuer('_base', '/assets/css/base.css', array('type'=>'style'));
myenqueuer('_fonts', '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600', array('type'=>'style', 'local'=>false));

myenqueuer('_lightbox2', '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightbox2/2.9.0/js/lightbox.min.js', array('deps'=>array('jquery'), 'local'=>false));
myenqueuer('_base', '/assets/js/base.js', array('deps'=>array('jquery')));
```

Comment: It gets errors with `myenqueuer('_normalize', '/assets/css/normalize.css', array('type=style'));`, what's the correct way to call it?

Comment: type and style will be separate strings, `array('type'=>'style')`, the first is the array key and the second is the value. and you have to use `=>`, not `=`.

Comment: That is not the only issue, if you test the code you'll see a few errors, also type script wont' run at all.

Comment: what errors? i'm getting Warning: filemtime(): stat failed for {my system filepath} but i think that is not related to the code, or are you getting the same?

Comment: 1. the var `src` shouldn't be used 3 times I think. 2. `media` value should be `all` by default. 3. `if else` style and script option isn't working here, always style no matter what type to set. 4. would be useful if you can post how you call the function`myenqueuer()` for both types.

Comment: ah yes, sorry, src is getting changed, reversing those lines will fix that. i've tested it after reversing and the scripts are included.